# WordPress the_date() doesn't work with Timber

Tags: timber

I've been using Timber to get list of posts. It works fine, but then I needed to "sort by the date" like this:

= Jan, 2nd =
Post 5
Post 4
= Jan, 1st =
Post 3
Post 2
Pos 1

WordPress function the_date() would do it, but I cannot get same result with Timber. the_date returns null

Index.php

```
$context            = Timber::context();
// $context['posts']    = new Timber\PostQuery();
$context['posts']   = Timber::get_posts(); // both doesn't work

$templates = array( 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

Archive.twig

```
<div class="s-archive__posts-list">
    {% for post in posts %}

        {{ the_date() }} // function registered via $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'the_date', 'the_date' ) );
        {{ fn('the_date') }} - doesn't work too. I was guessing, maybe, fourth param of this function the case (echo) but it's not {{ fn('the_date', 'M, Y', '', '', false ) }}. 

        {% include 'content/content-archive.twig' %}

    {% endfor %}
</div><!-- /s-archive__posts-list -->
```

What do I have to do to make it work as I expected?

**UPDATE**
It works with

$context['posts']   = Timber::query_posts();

Answer (score 0):

The question states that a call to the Wordpress function the_date() is returning null.

This is because the_date function will just echo the date if it has no other parameters and will not return a value. The full call to the_date has this form

the_date( string $format = '', string $before = '', string $after = '', bool $echo = true )

The default value for echo is true - if you want it to return a value instead then you need to set this parameter to false. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/

for a full description.

Wordpress also provides a get_the_date function which doesn't echo but always returns a date see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/

I am not familiar with Timber so do not know what is best for exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried set echo to false (that was mentioned in my question) but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to set echo false in the_date call - does Timber pass such parameters?

Comment: {{ fn('the_date', 'M, Y', '', '', false ) }}

It should, the first param is function name, others are its params like it would be in WordPress

Comment: Can you use dev tools on your browser look at the actual code that's being generated immediately after <div class="s-archive__posts-list"> - I assume you've just got your {{ fn('the_date', 'M, Y', '', '', false ) }} there rather than the call to the_date which was previously registered? Your parameters look fine. If it doesn't work could you try {{fn('get_the_date')}} instead, not passing any parameters, just to see if the date is actually put in there by Timber?

Comment: I solved it by replacing timber context to query_posts. Not sure is it a good idea or not but at least it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function like `the_date()`, that function will rely on a `$post` variable that is set as a global. However, in Timber we don’t rely on the `$post` global, because oftentimes, it’s harder to control.

Instead, we work with properties and methods on `post` itself. For a post’s date, you can use [`{{ post.date }}`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#date).

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.date }}

    {% include 'content/content-archive.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way, you don’t have to register function with `$twig->addFunction()`, either.